# What kind of testing equipment is used for UPS (>15 kVA)?

Tags: ups, testing

I work at IT division of a bank. Currently we need to order some Double Conversion True Online UPS ( Uninterruptible Power Supply) systems for our our new data center. The required ratings for UPS are 15kVA & 30kVA. I need to to know what kind of procedures are followed and equipments used during factory test/ witness test of UPS system. I want to know specifically which equipment is used for power measurement of ups. From web, I across of few names -Power Analyzer, Spectrum Analyzer . But I need an exact answer. and what parameters are tested with this equipment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to leave the testing of systems with rated powers of 15kVA and 30kVA to certified professionals. Even if you could get your hand on equipment to test a UPS with mentioned power, it would be extremely expensive !

Power Analyzers and Spectrum Analyzers are not meant to test UPSes. They are intended for analyzing equipment that generates less than 1000x the power you are looking at !

So: contact the professionals who will install this equipment for you !